# What is at the end of PGP blob?

Tags: encryption, pgp

I am  trying to decrypt a portion of an email that is encrypted with PGP.  In the examples I looked at, the end of the encrypted data had an "===" then some characters.  Are they part of the format?

Example
vNg===eWY7

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic as it's not a programming question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there is a newline character missing in-between the second and third equal sign. The message should be ending somewhat like this:

```
vNg==
=eWY7
```

The first two (it might be zero to two, depending on the encrypted input) equal signs are used as padding for the ASCII-armoring, as stated in [section 6.3 of RFC 4880](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-6.3).

The third (last) equal sign introduces the checksum, es described in [section 6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-6).

Comment: Thanks.  You are right, I lost the newline in my copy/paste.  Thanks for the info.